# Call nested function from another function in python?

Tags: python

I have a function inside inside another and a third function. How can I call my nested function inside of my third function? Is there any special libraries I can use? I am not allowed to edit a() or b(), only c().

```
def a():
    def b():
        print("hi")

def c():
    # code only here to call b() to print
```

Comment: Why did you nest it if you want to call it from outside?

Comment: These were the specifications

Comment: OK, then the specifications are generally broken for reasonable code.  You have an answer below that will technically get you what you need.  But I would resoundingly reject this code if it were submitted in a code review.

Comment: Agree. I did not write the specifications so I have been struggling for the last week.

Comment: If you need to access the function "b" which is inside another function "a" and you want to access it from the function "c", then you should define "b" in a scope that both "a" and "c" can see and use it.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this, function `b` is defined locally within `a`. This means that it cannot be accessed by default outside of `a`. There are two main ways to solve this, but both involve modifying `a`:

1. The `global` keyword (not recommended)

   ```
   def a():
       global b
       def b():
           print("hi")
   ```

   Here the `global` keyword sets `b` up as a global variable, so that you can then access it by calling it normally from within `c`. [This is generally frowned upon.](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)
2. Returning the function from `a` and passing it to `c`

   ```
   def a():
       def b():
           print("hi")
       return b

   def c(b):
       #your code
   ```

   Then, when you call `c`, you should pass `b` to it, which `a` will have returned. You can either do so thus:

   ```
   b = a()
   c(b)
   ```

   Or you can simply call `a` every time you call `c`, thus:

   ```
   c(a())
   ```

   If you choose to do this, you can then define `c` thus:

   ```
   def c():
       b = a()
       #your code here
   ```

   which would allow you to simply call `c` normally, thus:

   ```
   `c()`
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do but I am not allowed to edit a() or b() functions...I really don't see how it'll be possible without that return statement for b(). :(

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to the way that Python scope works. b() is local to a(), and so does not exist within c().

EDIT: commenter is correct, the suggestion I initially gave doesn't work -- so this definitely just isn't possible.

Comment: Yeah I have been researching solutions for the past week and I am convinced it cannot be done. I was given a small assignment to do this..

Answer (score 0):

As explained here, you cannot directly call a function included inside another. But, you can play around a bit and make it indirectly possible.

You could try calling functions via arguments and parameter values to call the function you want inside another function.

```
def a(invoke=None):
    def b():
       print('b')

    if invoke == 'b':
        b()


def c():
    a(invoke='b')

c()
```

The result is:

```
b
```

You can even pass arguments to these function if you want:

```
def a(invoke=None, a_parameter=None):
    def b(b_parameter=None):
        if b_parameter == None:
            print('b')
        if b_parameter == 'b1':
            print('b1')
        if b_parameter == 'b2':
            print('b2')

    if invoke == 'b':
        b(b_parameter = a_parameter)


def c(parameter=None):
    a(invoke='b', a_parameter = parameter)

c()
```

Result:

```
b
```

But:

```
c('b1')
```

Result:

```
b1
```