# Using inner function in other function

Tags: python

I would need to use a function defined inside other function. Is that possible?
`_f1` is defined in `f`, is it possible to use `_f1` in `f2`?

```
def f():
    def _f1():
        return "f1"
    return _f1()

def f2():
  return f._f1()

print(f2())
```

Comment: Welcome Maciej to Stackoverflow! The best thanks you can give to other users is by upvoting those answers who helped you the most, and accepting the best one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call nested function from another function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786308/call-nested-function-from-another-function-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Three options I see:

1. Declare a variable before the function runs and then pass the new function to that variable. Now you can access it from the other function:

```
func_variable = None

def f():
    def _f1():
        return "f1"
    func_variable = _f1

def f2():
  return func_variable()

print(f2())
```

2. Return the inner function and execute it.

```
def f():
    def _f1():
        return "f1"
    return _f1

def f2():
  inner_func = f()
  return inner_func()

print(f2())
```

3. Turn it into a class

```
class InnerFuncClass:
    inner_func = None

    def __init__(self):
        def _f1():
            return "f1"
        self.inner_func = _f1

f = InnerFuncClass()

def f2():
  return f.inner_func()

print(f2())
```

As an aside, you don't need semicolons in Python.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a class.

```py
class f:
    def __new__(self):
        return f._f1()
    @staticmethod
    def _f1():
        return 'f1'

def f2():
    return f._f1()

print(f())
>>> 'f1'
print(f2())
>>> 'f1'
```

While other answers are correct I think that one should consider a more complicated problem. For example where the function `f` has multiple inner function which it uses and the it returns 1 value. In this case it is not reasonable to return all child functions just to use it in other functions.

With this solution you are able to create multiple child functions and return only 1 value when the class `f()` is called (defined in the `__new__` function).

For example when you want to calculate the circumference times the area of a circle:

```
import math
class f:
    def __new__(self, radius):
        circumference = self.circumference(radius)
        area = self.area(radius)
        return circumference * area
    @staticmethod
    def circumference(radius):
        return math.pi * 2 * radius
    @staticmethod
    def area(radius):
        return math.pi * radius**2

def area(radius):
    return f.area(radius)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many things are being mixed here. To run the `_f1` function you first must return it from `f`. But you're calling it, so what is returned from `f` *is* the return value of `_f1`.

To call `_f1` *outside* the function you would use:

```py
def f():
    def _f1():
        return "f1"
    return _f1    

def f2():
  return f()()

print(f2())
```

As you see, `f2` is now calling `f`, which is returning `_f1` without executing it. Then, you can "execute this return value" (that's why the `()()` appears, you are in fact calling two functions at once), and *ta-da*, you are calling `_f1` outside the function `f`.

Answer (score 1):

For batter understanding, I will explain inner function by an example:

```
def OuterFunc(text): 
text = text 

def InnerFunc(): 
    print(text) 

InnerFunc() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
       OuterFunc('Fayzan Bhatti!')
```

**Output be like that:**  `Fayzan Bhatti`

Answer (score 1):

For returning a function from another function , do the following:

```
def f1():
   def f2():
      #do something here
   return f2 # note that I returning f1 and not f1()


def f():
   f2 = f1()
   
   # now call f2
   f2()
```

Note that f1 returns the f1 object and not f1(). `f1()` is basically calling the function. Another thing, the `.` operator is to be used only for objects and their corresponding member functions or variables. So you cannot use something like `f1._f1()`

**Edit** Although I should make it clear that functions in python are also objects.

If your functions are small and one liners, you can check out [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) operator.